# pyrus with php5.2.11?

Tags: php, pear, pyrus

Well, i'm trying to install pyrus on my server but the install failed. i'm guessing it is because of my php version so my question is Can we install Pyrus on a server that is using php5.2.11 ? 
is there any minimum requirement ?

Comment: Title of the documentation is "Using Pyrus, the PEAR Installer for PHP 5.3+", so my guess is "No"

Comment: Please note that PHP 5.2 was declared end of life nearly two years ago. It is a very long way out of date. If you value your site security, you *must* upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.2 does not support namespaces. Pyrus uses namespaces, so it cannot be used with PHP < 5.3.0.